# Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in // как лучше сделать

Tags: php

Ку, в общем есть метод - в котором я записываю данные в массив, с помощью добавление нового элемента [], однако при расширении - этот метод начал давать ошибку: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in, я понял что скорее всего это из за, 'status' => 'Pending' и попробовал переделать на 'status' => array('status' => 'Pending') однако ошибка не ушла, поэтому прошу помочь решить проблему координально, подскажите как лучше организовать работу данного метода:

Текст ошибки:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in
> /Users/leonidbasov/Projects/zzz.lk2.ru/engine/direct.php:920 Stack
> trace: #0
> /Users/leonidbasov/Projects/zzz.lk2.ru/module/logs/logs.php(197):
> engine\direct::getKeyStatistics(1) #1
> /Users/leonidbasov/Projects/zzz.lk2.ru/module/logs/logs.php(41):
> module\logs\logs::defoult() #2 [internal function]:
> module\logs\logs::Start() #3
> /Users/leonidbasov/Projects/zzz.lk2.ru/engine/systems.php(34):
> call_user_func('\module\logs\lo...') #4
> /Users/leonidbasov/Projects/zzz.lk2.ru/index.php(8):
> engine\systems::Start() #5 {main} thrown in
> /Users/leonidbasov/Projects/zzz.lk2.ru/engine/direct.php on line 920

Код метода:

```
public static function getKeyStatistics($site_id): array
    {
        $result = array();
        $site = systems::$db->select('site', ['id', 'domen', 'region', 'direct_search_id'], ['id' => $site_id])[0];
        $geo = systems::$db->select('cities', ['GeoRegionId'], ['i' => $site['region']])[0];
        $data = systems::$db->select('update', ['data'], ['type' => 'report'])[0]['data'];
        if (isset($site['direct_search_id'])) {
            $home = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
            $patchname = "{$home}/common/direct/domens/{$site['domen']}/direct/";
            $campaing_id = $site['direct_search_id'];
            $namefile = "keywords@{$site['domen']}@{$campaing_id}.json";
            if (file_exists($patchname . $namefile)) {
                $json_keywords = file_get_contents($patchname . $namefile);
                $keywords = json_decode($json_keywords, true);
                $array_keywords = array();
                foreach ($keywords['Keywords'] as $key => $keyword) {
                    array_push($array_keywords, $keyword['Keyword']);
                }
                $array_keywords = array_chunk($array_keywords, 100);
                $count = 1;
                foreach ($array_keywords as $key => $array_keyword) {
                    //добавить сюда количество отчетов в очереди и так же добавить в условие о не более 5 отчетов
                    if ($count <= 5) {
                        $report_id = self::greatStaticReport($array_keyword, $geo['GeoRegionId']);
                        $data[] = array(
                            'id' => $report_id['data'],
                            'time' => time(),
                            'site_id' => $site_id,
                            'status' => 'Pending'
                        );
                    } else {
                        $result['error'] = "Более 500 ключевых слов";
                    }
                }
                $data = serialize($data);
                systems::$db->update('update', ['data' => $data], ['type' => 'report']);
            } else {
                $result['error'] = "Нет файла с ключевыми словами по адресу: {$patchname}{$namefile}";
                return $result;
            }
        } else {
            $result['error'] = "Нет ID компании в базе";
            return $result;
        }
        return array();
    }
```

920 строчка это начало этой функнции:

```
 $data[] = array(
                            'id' => $report_id['data'],
                            'time' => time(),
                            'site_id' => $site_id,
                            'status' => 'Pending'
                        );
```

Заранее спасибо за советы (ранее я использовал аррау пуш, но в итоге она тоже работает оень странно.

Comment: А по'var_dump'ить? Посмотреть чего у вас там приходит? Где спортивный интерес то?

Comment: В начале вы делаете `$data = systems::$db->select(/*..*/)[0]['data'];` и `[0]['data']` выглядит так будто вы берёте берёте первую строку из ответа и из неё поле `data` что как раз и приводит к тому что в переменной оказывается строка. Ну и DaemonHK правильно сказал - var_dump в помощь

Comment: да я почти все по echoшил и проПринтРрил) может уже замылелось все, значения $report_id - норм, time() - тоже норм, $site_id - тоже норм, вот добавил только status - не работает.

Comment: Спасибо большое, действительно я пытаюсь к строке $data добавить массивные значения, забыл отсериализить полученную дату и перевести ее в массив! Ребят спасибо большое! Наверное мозги уже плывут по чуть чуть!